# MS Access Update All Dates in a Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table in Access where I am trying to update all the dates to one month prior than what the table shows. If the table shows 2012/11 it should be updated to 2012/10 etc. I'm assuming the best way to do this would be in VBA? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update TABLE Set [dateColumn] = DateAdd("m", -1, [dateColumn])
```

Comment: Ahhh excellent! That's perfect. Thanks Stuart, that was a great help!